# Une variante familière/argotique de améliorer

Tags: vocabulaire, néerlandais

Y a-t-il un mot plus argotique ou familier pour « améliorer » ? Je sais qu’« améliorer » n’est pas soutenu, mais je le dis trop souvent donc j’ai besoin d’un autre mot qui veut dire « rendre meilleur ».

Aux Pays-Bas les gens utilisent un mot issu du nom commun « cric », à savoir « opkrikken ». Ce mot s’emploie surtout pour désigner « en mettre un coup pour avoir des meilleures notes à l’école », mais n’est pas borné à ce cadre.

Quand je cherchais une traduction de ce mot avec Interglot, j’ai reçu une rangée de mots dont « pousser » me semblait la réponse la plus prometteuse. (Les autres étaient plutôt apparentés à « inciter », un mot qui appartient d’ailleurs à la suite de mots.)

Je veux savoir si on peut dire : « Il faut que je pousse mon anglais avant que je pars en Angleterre », ou « poussons ensemble nôtre santé en mangeant des pommes ». Si vous connaissez un meilleur mot, alors je vous prie de le donner.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Il ne me vient pas d'équivalent qui marche dans tous les cas. Par contre on peut chercher du côté de [*travailler*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/travailler#Synonymes) pour les cas où il s'agit de travailler

> Il faut que je *bosse* mon anglais avant de partir en Angleterre
>   Il faut que je *taffe* mon anglais avant de partir en Angleterre

Ou plus spécifiquement comme synonyme d'*étudier*

> Il faut que je *potasse* mon anglais avant de partir en Angleterre
>   Il faut que je *buche* mon anglais avant de partir en Angleterre

Pour la santé, je n'ai trouvé que *soigner*

> Soignons ensemble nôtre santé en mangeant des pommes

Mais note que la première personne du pluriel est plutôt soutenu en français actuel.

Comment: +1 pour "potasse mon anglais"

Comment: J'aimerais noter que *bosser*, *taffer* et *potasser* sont tous des expressions(verbes) strictement français de France.

Comment: Il y a aussi l'anglicisme *booster* qu'on entend assez régulièrement dans ce sens (*J'ai intérêt à booster mon anglais avant de...*). (note : je ne soutiens pas cet emploi, je le rapporte ;-))